# Git commit: reset Vim error state

Tags: vim, git

When I make a new Git commit (`git commit`) and it enters Vim, sometimes it happens that I make a small typo when I want to save the commit-message-file. E.g. I type `:Wq` instead of the usual `:wq`.

Vim reports an error then. Then, when I correctly save the file and quit Vim, Git says that Vim reported an error and it aborts the commit.

How can I avoid that? I.e. how can I reset the Vim error state so that Git doesn't think that Vim had an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running OSX? maybe [that will help](http://tooky.github.com/2010/04/08/there-was-a-problem-with-the-editor-vi-git-on-mac-os-x.html). It seems you have to call vim which its full path. Just add it to your config `git config --global core.editor /usr/bin/vim`